# How remove or reset mysql password!

Tags: mysql, password, reset

I test all the suggested answers but still I canon't reset or remove password or even reinstall the mysql db on Ubuntu 16.04,
Is there any ohter idea?

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Tested all suggested answers?  Could you be more specific and post what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal
2. `sudo mysql -u root`
3. `use mysql;`
4. `SELECT user, plugin FROM user;`
5. `UPDATE user SET plugin = "mysql_native_password" WHERE user = "root" ;`
6. `SELECT user, plugin FROM user;`
7. `exit`
8. `service mysql restart`

Comment: You cant use sudo mysql -u root when you dont have the password

Answer (score -1):

Have you can update new for the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux. Enter the following lines below:

```
1. Stop the MySQL Server: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. Start the mysqld configuration: sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
3. Login to MySQL as root: mysql -u root mysql
4. Replace "newpassword" with your new password:

UPDATE
  mysql.user
SET
  Password = PASSWORD('newpassword')
WHERE
  User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

> ```
> Note: on some versions, if password column doesn't exist, you may want to try:
> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
> ```

After changed pass success. however, it works.

References:

1. http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html